# MySQL: using random function in existing table for generating derived column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i have a table 'product' with column 'category' which consists of 10 different categories without a column category_id. i want to derive a table with new column category_id for each category.

```
select product_id,description,category, round(rand(10)) as category_id from product;
select product_id,description,category, rand( over partition by 10) from product;
```

using above query i have tried "round(rand())" however this gives only 0 and 1, but i want it to allocate category_id for 10 products from 1 to 10.

Also i want to retrieve the products from two random category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FLOOR(1+ rand() * 10)  this will give you a number between 1 and 10

```
select product_id,description,category,FLOOR(1+ rand() * 10) as category_id from product;
```

Comment: Thanks for quick update, still it dont creates unique number, i can see same number repeated.    

    `select product_id,description,category,FLOOR(1+ rand() * 10) as category_id from 
    product group by category;`    

Also under each category i have many products. Goal is to retrieve group of products listed in any random category

Comment: show some data and also wanted result, the code above generates random numbers between 1 to 10. random also includes that numbers will repeat.

Comment: used query: 
    `select product_id,description,category, FLOOR(1+ rand() * 10) as category_id from product group by category; `    
output:
    
product_id, Description, category, category_id
1          Biscuits Baked goods 4
11         Coke Beverages 1
18          Ariel Cleaning products 3
25     Barbecue Sauce Condiments / Sauces 2
    
expected output is as below:
    
product_id, description, category, category_id
1          Biscuits Baked goods       c1
11         Coke Beverages       c2
18          Ariel Cleaning products c3
25 Barbecue Sauce Condiments / Sauces c4

Comment: please edit your post and add not only result but also where the resulr comes from

Comment: Thanks , i got the correct query, below query works as per my expectations, i work using MySQL workbench.

solution:

    `select p.product_id, p.description,p.category from product p  join
(select c.product_id,c.category from product c order by rand() limit 2) cc on cc.category=p.category;`